# Is it grammatically correct to say 'value within time interval' or 'value within signal segment'?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I have following signal graph.

[image]

Is the following sentences are correct (Y-Axis values are called say, M value)?

1) The M values are quite high within the time interval [1870, 1180].

2) The M values are quite low within the signal segment k.

I am actually confused between: within vs during vs for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your expressions are intelligible.  Neither sounds entirely natural to the ears of a native speaker.

The problem is not grammatical, but semantic, and arises because  you are using space (i.e. the X axis) to represent an interval of time. This allows you to use both spatial and temporal expressions to describe the picture and what it represents.

You may recall Alfred Korzybski's admonition that [**the map is not the territory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation). Your graph is a map.  Your verbal descriptions may apply to either the map or the territory, but if you use both it's easy for the reader to get confused or distracted.

- **Within** is a spatial expression, e.g. a thing can lie *within an enclosure*.  It can also be applied to things where time is part of the enclosure, e.g. *within Beethoven's First Symphony there are four movements.*   It's "map-like" in its associations.
- **During** is a temporal expression. You might, for example, imagine yourself listening to the symphony in a concert hall, and that *during the first movement you received a phone call,* which you answered *during the intermission*.  You wouldn't describe these actions as happening *within* either the performance or the intermission.  For your "signal", *during* is more "territory-like", i.e. you are talking about "what is really happening" as opposed to pointing out a feature on the map.
- **For** can be used in either way, e.g. I could walk *for a mile* or *for an hour*. However, a reader familiar with computer programming will likely associate *for* with [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration), with its sense of moving along a sequence of events (like footsteps).

If your larger objective is to describe your data to the reader, I would suggest using a simple and consistent style that stays with either the map or the territory.  For example, if you use the map (spatial) form, describe first the *enclosure* and second its *properties*, e.g.

- In the decade from 1870 to 1880, the M values were high.
- In the interval highlighted in Segment k (1897 to 1913), the M values were low.